# Can I find out my filesystem quota as a user with no administrative rights?

Tags: linux, filesystems, quota

As a bonus: can I see what % I am currently using?

Answer (score 2):

Run the `quota` command.  It works for an unprivileged user to find out their own quota use, even on NFS mounted filesystems.

Comment: I would suggest you run quota with the -h flag so it displays the quota as an easy to read value.

Comment: On Debian, the flag is -s, -h is the help